# Magento 2.3 Type Error occurred when creating object: Magecomp\Imageclean\Model\ResourceModel\Imageclean\Grid\Collection\Interceptor

Tags: collection, upgrade, magento2.3.2, interceptor

I am using under given module.
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-image-clean.html

Till Magento 2.3.1 it's working perfectly.
After upgrade to 2.3.2 it giving under given error:

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
>   Magecomp\Imageclean\Model\ResourceModel\Imageclean\Grid\Collection\Interceptor

Please Guide me to solve this.

> File:Magecomp\Imageclean\Model\ResourceModel\Imageclean\Grid\Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Magecomp\Imageclean\Model\ResourceModel\Imageclean\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Collection extends \Magecomp\Imageclean\Model\ResourceModel\Imageclean\Collection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    protected $aggregations;
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $curstoreid;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface $configScopeConfigInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share answer if you figured the problem, looking for same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MageComp Has upgraded their extension after your post. so please download it and check it again. i have downloaded and compile and check everything. it's working good.

Answer (score 1):

> Remove Cache it will solve the problem

```
rm -rf var/generation/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/_requirejs/ var/cache var/di var/page_cache pub/static/_cache
```

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: Execute so many times. Tried all CLI no luck.

Answer (score 1):

In My Case StoreManagerInterface is not Injecting in **`Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Collection`** Class and i was passing to StoreManagerInterface to Constructor of Grid COllection which is causing problem when I removed it started working Fine